# How to only disable destruction of objects in thread-local-storage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, global-variables, destructor

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;

struct A
{
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }    
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }
};

A g_a;

int main()
{
    thread([]()
    {
        thread_local A a;
        this_thread::sleep_for(24h);
    }).detach();

    exit(0); // not ok
    quick_exit(0); // still not ok
}
```

- Global objects and objects in `thread-local-storage` will be
  destructed after calling `exit(0)`;
- Global objects and objects in `thread-local-storage` will not be
  destructed after calling `quick_exit(0)`;

Is it possible:

**Global objects are destructed after calling `some_exit_func(0)`; while objects in `thread-local-storage` are not destructed.**

> ***Problem background:***
>
> I have a big legacy project, which has used `thread-local-storage` to
>   store many C++ objects; before C++11, these objects will not be
>   destructed automatically, so the former writer explicitly calls their
>   destructors.
>
> Now, I want to recompile it with a C++11 compiler; I am faced with such a
>   problem:
>
> - If I use `exit(0)`, the objects in `thread-local-storage`  will be    double-destructed;
> - If I use `quick_exit(0)`, the global variables will not be    destructed.

Comment: Can you show how those explicit destructor calls are done (include it in your code sample) ? Can't you just remove those explicit destructor calls ?

Comment: As @SanderDeDycker says, look into removing the explicit destructor calls. it seems like you are trying to solve a symptom of a problem rather then solving the problem itself.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot modify those legacy code. The crash is due to double lock a posix mutex; similar to double destruction. If I replace `exit` with `quick_exit`, the crash will not be triggered; but the global variables will not be destructed, which is not acceptable.

Comment: a double lock on a mutex ? I think you really need to show the representative code for that (provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so we can understand the actual problem.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, Yes. `pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);` returns `EDEADLK`.

Comment: Remove the check for `EDEADLK`? You have broken code and don't want to fix it. There is not much anyone can do here until that changes.

Comment: @nwp, For some reason, I cannot modify those legacy code.